# Why the home page cannot be accessed / spring boot application

Tags: spring, maven, tomcat, spring-boot

I am little confused with the structure of spring boot application, and now I have a spring boot application which can run successfully and the embedded server-tomcat can also be started with no errors. But, when I access the home page with http://localhost:8451/fe/admin-ui, the browser responses with a blank page, and there are errors on the server log

```
org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:393) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.flushBuffer(ByteChunk.java:426) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:342) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flush(OutputBuffer.java:317) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.flush(CoyoteOutputStream.java:110) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8JsonGenerator.flush(UTF8JsonGenerator.java:1022) ~[jackson-core-2.6.5.jar:2.6.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValue(ObjectWriter.java:891) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.5.jar:2.6.5]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:264) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.java:100) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:222) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(HttpEntityMethodProcessor.java:183) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:80) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:126) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:814) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:737) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:969) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:860) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:845) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:720) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:468) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:391) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:318) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:445) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:304) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:181) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_101]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_101]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:51) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:65) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:471) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel.write(NioChannel.java:124) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioBlockingSelector.write(NioBlockingSelector.java:101) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.write(NioSelectorPool.java:172) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioOutputBuffer.writeToSocket(InternalNioOutputBuffer.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioOutputBuffer.addToBB(InternalNioOutputBuffer.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioOutputBuffer.access$000(InternalNioOutputBuffer.java:41) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioOutputBuffer$SocketOutputBuffer.doWrite(InternalNioOutputBuffer.java:320) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.ChunkedOutputFilter.doWrite(ChunkedOutputFilter.java:118) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractOutputBuffer.doWrite(AbstractOutputBuffer.java:256) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.coyote.Response.doWrite(Response.java:501) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:388) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    ... 42 common frames omitted

2016-11-13 20:50:58.141 ERROR 13724 --- [nio-8451-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost]           : Exception Processing ErrorPage[errorCode=0, location=/error]
```

I googled it and someone says that it could be induced by firewall, auti-virus, but after I turned them off and the errors still there. In addition, I am not sure whether the URL entered is right, below is the main class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Controller
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class AdminUIApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AdminUIApplication.class, args);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/fe/**")
    public String redirect() {
        return "forward:/";
    }

}
```

In addition, below is part of information printed during starting the server

```
2016-11-13 20:47:58.361  INFO 13724 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8451 (http)
2016-11-13 20:47:58.394  INFO 13724 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2016-11-13 20:47:58.396  INFO 13724 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.32
2016-11-13 20:47:59.001  INFO 13724 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2016-11-13 20:47:59.003  INFO 13724 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2998 ms
2016-11-13 20:47:59.699  INFO 13724 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.e.ServletRegistrationBean        : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2016-11-13 20:47:59.705  INFO 13724 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2016-11-13 20:47:59.706  INFO 13724 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2016-11-13 20:47:59.707  INFO 13724 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2016-11-13 20:47:59.707  INFO 13724 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2016-11-13 20:48:01.150  INFO 13724 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@7164ca4c: startup date [Sun Nov 13 20:47:56 MST 2016]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@68999068
2016-11-13 20:48:01.331  INFO 13724 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/fe/**]}" onto public java.lang.String gov.samhsa.c2s.adminui.AdminUIApplication.redirect()
2016-11-13 20:48:01.336  INFO 13724 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2016-11-13 20:48:01.336  INFO 13724 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2016-11-13 20:48:01.347  INFO 13724 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.c.a.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter      : Adding welcome page: class path resource [static/index.html]
2016-11-13 20:48:01.399  INFO 13724 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Root mapping to handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController]
2016-11-13 20:48:01.471  INFO 13724 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2016-11-13 20:48:01.471  INFO 13724 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2016-11-13 20:48:01.578  INFO 13724 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2016-11-13 20:48:02.209  WARN 13724 --- [           main] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : No URLs will be polled as dynamic configuration sources.
2016-11-13 20:48:02.210  INFO 13724 --- [           main] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : To enable URLs as dynamic configuration sources, define System property archaius.configurationSource.additionalUrls or make config.properties available on classpath.
2016-11-13 20:48:02.226  WARN 13724 --- [           main] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : No URLs will be polled as dynamic configuration sources.
2016-11-13 20:48:02.231  INFO 13724 --- [           main] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : To enable URLs as dynamic configuration sources, define System property archaius.configurationSource.additionalUrls or make config.properties available on classpath.
2016-11-13 20:48:02.406  INFO 13724 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
```

The following is the related index.html:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>
<html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>
<html class="no-js lt-ie9">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
<!--<![endif]-->
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title c2s-page-title>C2S | Admin Portal</title>

        <base href="/admin-ui/">

        <!-- INSPINIA RELATED CSS START -->
        <!-- Font awesome -->
        <link href="assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- Bootstrap  -->
        <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- Main Inspinia CSS files  -->
        <link href="assets/css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link id="loadBefore" href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link  href="assets/css/plugins/iCheck/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link  href="assets/css/plugins/angular-notify/angular-notify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link  href="assets/css/plugins/datapicker/datepicker3.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- INSPINIA RELATED CSS END -->
        <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
        <!-- POC styles + vendor style-->
        <!-- compiled CSS  -->

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/Consent2Share-0.13.0.css" />

    </head>
    <body class="grey fixed-sidebar" ng-controller="AppController as AppVm">
        <div ui-view ></div>
        <!-- INSPINIA RELATED JS  -->

        <!-- jQuery and Bootstrap -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script  type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script  type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script  type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/plugins/jasny/jasny-bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <!-- MetsiMenu -->
        <script  type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/plugins/metisMenu/jquery.metisMenu.js"></script>

        <!-- SlimScroll -->
        <script  type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/plugins/slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Peace JS -->
        <script  type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/plugins/pace/pace.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Custom and plugin javascript -->
        <script  type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/inspinia.js"></script>

        <!-- Main Angular scripts-->

        <!-- compiled JavaScript -->

        <script type="text/javascript" src="vendor/angular/angular.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="vendor/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="vendor/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="vendor/angular-aria/angular-aria.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="vendor/angular-messages/angular-messages.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="vendor/angular-loading-bar/build/loading-bar.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="vendor/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="vendor/ngstorage/ngStorage.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="vendor/checklist-model/checklist-model.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="vendor/x2js/xml2json.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="vendor/angular-jwt/dist/angular-jwt.js"></script>


        <!--<script  type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/angular/angular.min.js"></script>-->
        <script  type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.0.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/angular-idle.js"></script>
        <script  type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/plugins/iCheck/icheck.min.js"></script>
        <script  type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/plugins/angular-notify/angular-notify.min.js"></script>
        <script  type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/plugins/datapicker/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

        <!-- Compile application JS files will be injected between the angularand endangular comments below. -->
        <!-- angular -->

        <script src="templates-app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="app/security/security.module.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="app/security/services/urlAuthorizationConfigurer.service.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="app/security/services/profile.service.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="app/security/services/oauthToken.service.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="app/security/services/authorization.service.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="app/security/services/authenticationInterceptor.service.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="app/security/services/authentication.service.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="app/security/security.constant.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="app/patientMedicalDocument/patientMedicalDocument.module.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="app/patientMedicalDocument/services/patientMedicalDocument.service.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="app/patientMedicalDocument/patientMedicalDocument.config.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="app/patientMedicalDocument/directives/c2sRetrieveDocumentResult.directive.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="app/patientMedicalDocument/directives/c2sRetrieveDocument.directive.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="app/patientMedicalDocument/directives/c2sPatientMedicalDocumentSearch.directive.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="app/patientMedicalDocument/controllers/RetrieveDocument.controller.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="app/patientMedicalDocument/controllers/PatientMedicalDocument.controller.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="app/patient/patient.module.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="app/patient/patient.config.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="app/patient/directives/c2sShowPatientIdentifier.directive.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="app/patient/directives/c2sPatientVerfication.directive.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="app/patient/directives/c2sPatientCreateEdit.directive.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="app/patient/controllers/patientEdit.controller.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="app/patient/controllers/patientCreate.controller.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="app/layout/layout.module.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="app/layout/directives/c2sSideNavigation.directive.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="app/layout/directives/c2sRoleNavigation.directive.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="app/layout/directives/c2sProfileMenu.directive.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="app/layout/directives/c2sPageTitle.directive.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="app/layout/directives/c2sMinimalizeSidebar.directive.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="app/layout/directives/c2sIboxTools.directive.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="app/home/home.module.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="app/home/home.config.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="app/home/directives/c2sPatientSearch.directive.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="app/home/directives/c2sPatientList.directive.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="app/home/controllers/home.controller.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="app/error/error.module.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="app/error/services/error.service.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="app/error/error.constant.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="app/error/error.config.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="app/error/controllers/uncaught.controller.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="app/error/controllers/unauthorized.controller.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="app/data/data.module.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="app/data/service/patient.service.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="app/core/core.module.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="app/core/services/xmlParser.service.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="app/core/services/utility.service.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="app/core/services/notification.service.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="app/core/filters/zip.filter.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="app/core/filters/trustAsHTML.filter.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="app/core/filters/trimBeforeCharacter.filter.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="app/core/filters/phone.filter.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="app/core/filters/pcmProviderNameOrFacility.filter.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="app/core/filters/hasString.filter.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="app/core/filters/fileName.filter.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="app/core/directives/c2sValidateZipcode.directive.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="app/core/directives/c2sValidateSSN.directive.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="app/core/directives/c2sValidatePhoneNumber.directive.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="app/core/directives/c2sValidateName.directive.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="app/core/directives/c2sValidateEmail.directive.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="app/core/directives/c2sValidateDate.directive.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="app/core/directives/c2sUnsecureTopNavbar.directive.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="app/core/directives/c2sOutsideClick.directive.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="app/core/directives/c2sMultiSelectDate.directive.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="app/core/directives/c2sIcheck.directive.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="app/core/directives/c2sFormatDate.directive.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="app/core/directives/c2sDatepickerRange.directive.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="app/core/directives/c2sDatepicker.directive.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="app/core/directives/c2sContentWrapper.directive.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="app/core/directives/c2sCompareTo.directive.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="app/core/directives/c2sCheckAfterToday.directive.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="app/core/directives/c2sBackToPrevious.directive.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="app/core/core.constant.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="app/config/config.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="app/brand/brand.module.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="app/brand/brand.service.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="app/app.module.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="app/app.run.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="app/app.controller.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="app/app.config.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="app/account/account.module.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="app/account/directives/c2sOauthLogout.directive.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="app/account/directives/c2sOauthLogin.directive.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="app/account/controllers/login.controller.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="app/account/account.config.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <!-- endangular -->
    </body>
</html>
```

So, I wonder whether I give the right URL, and what are (possible) reasons the errors occur? Could you give me your comments?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you can following try 2 things.

1. Check your JAR/WAR whether the pages are wrapped in your archive.
2. Do you have rights on the folder.

Comment: 1. I checked the JAR again, the index.html is located in the fold of static.

Comment: 2. and I think I have the rights on the folder, the whole application has been cloned on my local folder.

Comment: In addition, I re-accessed the home page with the same URL through another browser, no errors occur this time, but I sitll got a blank page. What do you think, what other possible reasons that could occur a blank page without any errors in my case?

Comment: By any Chance have you added Context?

Comment: Ok, I read your question again and I understand you are trying to access Index.html(or ay page) when you hit the Rest Endpoint. As the application will return only String in response i.e.

Comment: "forward:/"..you have to use Response.TemporaryRedirect(uri), and define URI where you want to redirect.

Comment: thanks！@sandeshch  Then what is meaning of "forward:/" here ? I pulled the source code of application from github, and the application works well before they published it to the github, do you think the problem I face is that what you said ? I posted the related source code of index.html above.

Comment: I just tried again, the index.html can be accessed, but I cannot get any information of index.html posted above, could you help me to find what is possible reason ?

Comment: Can you add gitHub URL here? I will try to replicate.

Comment: Here is gitHub URL of related application: https://github.com/bhits/admin-portal-ui,  by the way, can I have you email address, more details about it if you need I will send you through email. Here is my email address: w.t.zhou74@gmail.com

Comment: sandesh.k.chaudhari@gmail.com